# Redirecionar um domínio para subpasta sem alterar a URL, mas não permitir o contrário?

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite

Eu estou com o seguinte problema, tenho uma aplicação com a seguinte estrutura:

- **app** - Pasta para armazenar arquivos do projeto como controllers e
  models.
- **public_html** - Armazena documentos públicos na web, como a index, uploads, css.
- **routes.php** - Gerencia as rotas do meu projeto, chamada pelo index.php na pasta public_html
- **.htaccess** - "o problema"

Preciso que quando um usuário acessar `exemplo.com`, a requisição seja redirecionada para minha pasta `public_html`, no caso o `index.php` dessa pasta seria acionado, e iria incluir o `routes.php` do diretório no nível acima, porém não desejo que a url fique `exemplo.com/public_html/index.php`.

Também não gostaria que fosse possível acessar a url diretamente como `exemplo.com/public_html`, ou seja, para evitar URLs duplicadas como `exemplo.com/index.php?pagina=1` e `exemplo.com/public_html/index.php?pagina=1`, queria que quando alguém realizar o acesso direto à esta página, ele seja redirecionado ao `exemplo.com`.

**Observações**: Utilizo o servidor Apache na distribuição Debian 8 e quero realizar essas configurações através do `.htaccess`, possuo o `mod_rewrite` ativo e funcional.

Não citei nenhum arquivo da `public_html`, mas acredito que talvez vou precisar de configurações no `.htaccess` de lá.

Pretendo implementar URLs amigáveis também.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver este problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui a solução para meu problema, mesclando várias dicas que encontrei na internet.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redireciona as requisições externas na public_html para a raiz
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+public_html/
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]

# Internamente reescreve a requisição de volta para a public_html
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public_html/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Ps: Isso não resolve o problema com URLs amigáveis, apenas resolve o acesso a pasta  public_html.